# How do I ask DB2 to return to me 1000 rows of data at a time out of 1million rows

Tags: sql, database, events, db2, simulation

I am currently building a **simulator** for an Event Processing Network(EPN). I have a static database that will act as the data source. My main table contains *Geo-locations* (lat/long coordinates) for automobiles.

Over the million(s) rows of coordinates available, I am thinking I need to retrieve on the order of 1000 rows at a time as I do not want to "flood" my EPN. The nature of my (real life) data source behaves in a way that geo-locations come in over time as automobiles proceed down a route. So I would like to fetch the earliest geo-data and progess through the static dataset in order of oldest-newest. This will at least give me the sequence of "order over time".

The plan is to put 1000 rows on a Rabbit queue, and allow a consumer to eat those all up, and then go get another 1000 rows until I get to the end of the table. At the end, I will start over with the first row again.

At first I was thinking that there might be a SQL language construct such as: "OPTIMIZE FOR n ROWS" or "FETCH FIRST n" - or some combination of both.

I found [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_sql_orderbyclause.htm) which says:

"*You can specify a large value of n in the OPTIMIZE FOR n ROWS clause of a SELECT statement to increase the number of DRDA query blocks that a DB2 server returns in each network transmission for a non scrollable cursor.*"

But now I am thinking there may be more complexity to getting down to what I want.

Do you guys have any suggestions for creating this type of behavior?

Comment: This is DB2 LUW, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to use the `ROW_NUMBER` OLAP Function, which would assign a number (in this case ordered by `GEO_DATE`), which you could then use to filter with the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GEO_DATE) AS rn
        A.*
        FROM your_table A
)
--WHERE rn BETWEEN 1 AND 1000
WHERE rn BETWEEN 1001 AND 2000
```

Comment: You guys on LUW don't have a multi-row [FETCH](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzfets.htm) into an array?  Isn't there some reasonable way to accomplish the equivalent?

Comment: @WarrentT -- You can via the program APIs, but, its not normally required as DRDA does the equivalent of multirow internally.

Comment: @bhamby -- So, the way I understand your example is that you have an internal (sub) select that gets all rows in order of Geo-Date. And the outer where clause will filter the which row numbers appear in the result set.

I'm not sure that this gets down to fetching 1000 rows at a time on a loop type behavior. No offense, but this seems like a manual query to change by hand - not an automated solution.

Am I understanding you correctly?